# Hello WebView Example for Android 4.4

Tags: android, eclipse, webview, sample

Is there an explicit example of code for using WebView using API 19 for Android 4.4 (using Eclipse & ADT)? There seem to have been a lot of changes in 4.4 and I am have been unable to make things work with the examples I have found, Google & elsewhere. (I admit in advance that I am just coming up to speed and may have missed something obvious so a full example would be awesome - and apologies in advance if I missed in searching)

Answer (score 1):

From Android Developer site:
There is the [Migrating to 4.4 help](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)
From the same:

> This change upgrades WebView performance and standards support for
>   HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript to match the latest web browsers. Any apps
>   using WebView will inherit these upgrades when running on Android 4.4
>   and higher.

For examples and code:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromium-webview-samples

More with:
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Also, check the overall difference, chrome webview from 4.4:
http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-44-kitkat-browser-and
http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-4-4-kitkat-browser-chrome-webview

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast response. So far, I have read all the relevant docs on the big change to 4.4 (I had webview working in a few hours from scratch a few years ago on android 2.2). I am using a Nexus 5 for test (got the .inf's working finally on that, too) but I can't anything but "favicon's can't find page url" messages in the eclipse unfiltered log. Again thank you for the ref's but I've tried hardware accel off and large heap and no luck so far.